# DJI mobile SDK, how to disable obstacle avoidance in Virtual Joystick control mode?

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I am trying to fly a DJI drone (Mavic 2 / Spark) autonomously using the DJI Mobile SDK. I am able to issue virtual joystick commands and the drone follows it. I have disabled obstacle/collision avoidance through the API. The problem is if there is an obstacle around the robot, it brakes and won't follow the issued virtual joystick commands. I disabled obstacle avoidance but still, the drone brakes and won't move (it won't move closer than ~2.5m towards the obstacle).

Findings:

- The default distance to brake at is ~2.5m from the obstacle (Mavic 2).
- Disabling obstacle avoidance works in regular P-Mode i.e. when using the RC.
- Disabling obstacle avoidance via SDK and switching to DJI-Go app confirms it has actually been disabled.
- Same behavior with DJI Spark

Can someone please advise how to disable obstacle avoidance for Virtual Joystick mode? I have already tried the following and other variants:

```
self.myFC.isVirtualStickAdvancedModeEnabled = NO;
[self.myFC.flightAssistant setCollisionAvoidanceEnabled:NO withCompletion:nil];
[self.myFC.flightAssistant setAdvancedPilotAssistanceSystemEnabled:NO withCompletion:nil];
[self.myFC.flightAssistant setActiveObstacleAvoidanceEnabled:NO withCompletion:nil];
[self.myFC.flightAssistant setUpwardsAvoidanceEnabled:NO withCompletion:nil];

[self.myFC sendVirtualStickFlightControlData:cmd withCompletion:nil];
```

I expected disabling obstacle avoidance should allow the drone to move irrespective of obstacle presence.
Thanks

Using the following SDK version

```
pod 'DJI-SDK-iOS', '~> 4.9.1'
pod 'DJI-UXSDK-iOS', '~> 4.9'
pod 'DJIWidget', '~> 1.2'
```

Comment: What order are you doing this in? I just got this to work with a Mavic 2. I first initialized the flight controller (setting roll pitch control mode, etc.), then set collision avoidance enabled = false with the flight assistant, then enabled virtual joy sticks. This was all in the Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm doing it in the same order as yours, in iOS. I tried disabling all, collisionAvoidance, upwardCollisionAvoidance, ActiveCollsionAvoidance, no avail.
So, you're saying the drone is able to get arbitrarily close to obstacles in joystick mode? (Android)

Comment: That's right - I tested exactly that yesterday and the collision avoidance was definitely disabled. It happily flew as close to obstacles as I would let it. I haven't touched many of the settings you referenced above (VirtualStickAdvancedMode, AdvancedPilotAssistanceSystem, ActiveObstacleAvoidance, and UpwardsAvoidance), so I'm not sure if that makes a difference or if it is an iOS SDK bug.

Comment: Thanks @CrumblyRock for putting in the effort to test. I will reference this to another thread where another user had similar issue on android.
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/212#issuecomment-483229458

Comment: I recently found that if I do VJ control by sending roll pitch angle commands the drone can get arbitrarily close to obstacles, however this is not the case when I send VJ x-y velocity commands.
@CrumblyRock what commands were you sending? Thanks

Comment: I am setting RollPitchControlMode to Velocity, YawControlMode to angular velocity, VerticalControlMode to velocity, and the RollPitchCoordinateSystem to Body.

Comment: Thanks @CrumblyRock, that's exactly what I had set. I'm in touch with DJI support, so let's see what's the issue.

Comment: any progress with that issue? i am experiencing the same problem